# MacBook Pro with Retina display to Apple TV using Airplay is glitchy

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, appletv, airplay

I have a 2013 MacBook Pro with Retina display running Mavericks and a brand new Apple TV (I've updated the software on it). When I use AirPlay to connect to my TV, one of two things happen.

1. It connects, then immediately disconnects, or
2. It connects, plays a video for 5-10 minutes, then disconnects. When it disconnects, it continues playing audio from the TV, but the video freezes on the TV. It still continues to play the video on my Mac.

How can I fix this? I haven't seen wireless connectivity issues, but would it help if I put an AirPort Express to extend the network in my bedroom (I have a new AirPort Time Capsule)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: open "Wireless Diagnostics" via Spotlight → Search/open Wireless Diagnostics → Window → Utilities and perform a wi-fi scan. Make sure that your router use a wireless channel with no/minimal other networks (you can change the channel via airport utility). If problem persists, try using the other wireless frequency (2.4ghz vs. 5ghz) via airport utility.

Next try streaming with [Beamer app](http://beamer-app.com) - much better video quality than airplay mirroring. Its a lovely app, and free to try. Solved all my airplay problems (have almost same setup; macbook retina + apple tv + airport extreme ac).

If problem persist, I guess I would try extending with an Airport Express (you can check the signal quality in wireless diagnostics).

Comment: The "wireless diagnostics" tip didn't do anything for me. Beamer however improves things a lot. Thanks.